# how to use play/pause in one button on ionic3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I Developing a New mobile Musical app in ionic3

Now In my Project, I Have a Two buttons

1.`play`button

2.`pause` button

Here I need some help

When user click `play` button then `play`button will get hide and show `pause` button.If users again click `pause` button then need to show `play` button

How to do this in ionic3??

Comment: const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);
const play = () => { 
    if (playing == true){
      // stop and start again
      player.playbackManager.pause(); 
      setPlaying(false);
    }else{
      // play 
      player.playbackManager.play();
      setPlaying(true);
    }
  };


  return (
   <div>
   <div className="controller-bar"> 
        <IonButton component="span" onClick={play}>
           
 {playing ? ( <PlayArrow />  ) : (   <Pause/> )}
        </IonButton> 
  </div>
  );
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to show/hide two buttons. You can just switch the icon to show `play` or `pause`.

```
<button ion-button (click)='startStopPlaying()' >
  <ion-icon [name]="isPlaying ? 'pause' : 'play' ">
</button>
```

And on controller:

```
startStopPlaying () {
  //your logic to play pause
  if(this.isPlaying) {
    //pause here
  } else {
    //play here
  }
  this.isPlaying = !this.isPlaying;
}
```

This way, you can same button for both action